flutter TextFormField validator not working for some fields
I have multiple fields that neeed to be validated for required in page but with the same code some filed was working fine & some was not can someone please help me.
As mention in code
_fullnameController
_phonenumberController
_alternatenumberController
_birthdateController

for these controllers, I was using the validator, but it was not working as expected only
_jobController, _familyinformationController, _mamkulController, _addressController 

were working OK with validator.
In the screenshot, you can see the exact issue
void _register() {
    if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Registration Successful')),
      );      
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'Your Details',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _fullnameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Full Name',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Full name is required';
                  } else if (value.length <= 6) {
                    return 'Full name must be more the 6 character';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _phonenumberController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty && value.length < 10) {
                    return 'Mobile Number is required';
                  } else if (value.length != 10) {
                    return 'Provided valid mobile number';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _qualificationController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Education',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Education is required';
                  } else if (value.length < 2) {
                    return 'Provided valid Education';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                onTap: () async {
                  DateTime? date = DateTime(1900);
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                  date = await showDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 17),
                      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 17));
                  _birthdateController.text =
                      DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(date!);
                },
                controller: _birthdateController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Birth Date',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Birth Date is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _jobController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Job',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Job is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _addressController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Address',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Address is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _familyinformationController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Family Information',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Family Information is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _mamkulController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Mamkul',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Mamkul is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _alternatenumberController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Alternate Mobile Number',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _birthplaceController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Birth Place',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _heightController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Height',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _gotraController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Gotra',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _ganController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Gan',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _nakshatrController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Nakshtra',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _nadiController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Nadi',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _bloodgroupController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Blood Group',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _register,
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Constant.HEADR_BACKGROUBD_COLOUR,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  'Save',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I want to add validator to fullname education those are present in the code

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

It is due to ListView. Use this code.
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    'Your Details',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _fullnameController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Full Name',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      print(("Name $value"));
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Full name is required';
                      } else if (value.length <= 6) {
                        return 'Full name must be more the 6 character';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _phonenumberController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty && value.length < 10) {
                        return 'Mobile Number is required';
                      } else if (value.length != 10) {
                        return 'Provided valid mobile number';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _qualificationController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Education',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Education is required';
                      } else if (value.length < 2) {
                        return 'Provided valid Education';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    onTap: () async {
                      DateTime? date = DateTime(1900);
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      date = await showDatePicker(
                          context: context,
                          initialDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 17),
                          firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                          lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 17));
                    },
                    controller: _birthdateController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Birth Date',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Birth Date is required';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _jobController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Job',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Job is required';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _addressController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Address',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Address is required';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _familyinformationController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Family Information',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Family Information is required';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _mamkulController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Mamkul',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Mamkul is required';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _alternatenumberController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Alternate Mobile Number',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _birthplaceController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Birth Place',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _heightController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Height',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _gotraController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Gotra',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _ganController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Gan',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _nakshatrController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Nakshtra',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _nadiController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Nadi',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _bloodgroupController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Blood Group',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _register,
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      // backgroundColor: Constant.HEADR_BACKGROUBD_COLOUR,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Save',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

